# Change The Text of a Button in Xamarin Android programmatically

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

how do i change the text label of my button after clicking it. I have a listview containing multiple selection item and i want all checked item in my listview go to button as a text

Comment: What you did till now? What is your efford?

Comment: i did toast what ever i pick in listview but i struggle to put text on what i've picked into button

Comment: What is your code? Please, update your question if you have new informations.

Comment: can you give me an example that i can get the items that i check in my listview and transfer the data to a textview ?

Comment: I read your question and comments, what do you want exactly, multiple selection of `ListView`, and get the selected items to a `TextView`, get what data from items? Or `Button`? But click the button to change its label? Your demand changed several times, could you please just show your code to help us understand.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT i just want to create a function like date picker ... but my plan is to create a listview inside a dialog and after checking the listview choices it will shown in button like datepicker.